# Golang print string as an array of bytes

Tags: arrays, json, go

What's the fmt code for printing a string as an array of bytes?

If I have a marshaled json object, I can print bytes like so:

```
type Fakejs struct {
    Fake string `json:"fake"`
}

fjs := Fakejs {Fake:"abc"}
mjs, err := json.Marshal(fjs)
fmt.Println(mjs)
```

Produces

```
[123 34 102 97 107 101 34 58 34 97 98 99 34 125]
```

Which is what I want.  However, with a regular string, I try this:

```
mystr := "{\"fake\":\"abc\"}"
fmt.Printf("mystr:\t %x \n", []byte(mystr))
```

And this produces:

```
7b2266616b65223a22616263227d
```

Which is not what I want.  What is the "%x"-like format code that will printf the string as an array of bytes.

Comment: `%v` prints the raw value in its default format: https://play.golang.org/p/W5F_BeOgX_g

Comment: Looks like an answer to me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

https://play.golang.org/p/eQcZm57k1C1

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    mystr := "{\"fake\":\"abc\"}"
    fmt.Printf("mystr:\t %v \n", []byte(mystr))
}
```

prints

```
mystr:   [123 34 102 97 107 101 34 58 34 97 98 99 34 125]
```